# How to encrypt decrypt string using MACTripleDES?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

How to encrypt and decrypt the string using MACTripleDES in C#? Is there any difference between MACTripleDES and TripleDES?

Comment: If a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) is secure, then you can't "decrypt" it. If you "encrypt" more than a block size, then you probably can't decrypt it anymore. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ArtjomB. then how can i get the original text back in MACTripleDES. I've tried similar like TripleDES

Comment: Cross-posted on Crypto.SE: [What is the difference between MACTripleDES and TripleDES?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31754/13022)

Answer (score 4):

MACTripleDES uses [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC). CBC-MAC uses the CBC mode after padding the message with zeros. This is specified in the withdrawn FIPS 113 specification (DAA). Only the last block is kept:

[image: CBC-MAC]

This means that each and every block of plaintext data before that cannot be retrieved. That is, unless you know the plaintext of the last blocks, in that case you can XOR it with the last block, retrieve the previous ciphertext, and calculate the plaintext by decryption.

TripleDES in CBC mode on the other hand outputs all the blocks of ciphertext, *before* using it as vector for the next block of plaintext.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class MACTripleDESTest
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // example key
            byte[] key = new byte[24];
            for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
            {
                key[i] = (byte) i;
            }

            // uses CBC MAC with zero initialization vector and Zero padding
            MACTripleDES macTDES = new MACTripleDES(key);
            byte[] result = macTDES.ComputeHash(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 });

            TripleDES tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tdes.Key = key;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            ICryptoTransform tf = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] pt = tf.TransformFinalBlock(result, 0, tdes.BlockSize / 8);
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(pt));
        }
    }
}
```

which will result in:

```
01-02-03-04-00-00-00-00
```

---

[CBC-MAC is rather insecure:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC#Attack_methods)

- when used together with CBC mode encryption and the same key it fails completely
- it will not deliver full security for dynamically sized messages
- the 3DES block size is rather small

Use either AES-CMAC, HMAC or authenticated encryption instead.

Answer (score 2):

A [Message Authentication Code (MAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) is similar to a hash in that you can't "decrypt" it. The input is usually some arbitrarily long message, but the output has the size of the Triple DES block size which is limited to 64 bit. Since the input can be larger than the output, you should easily see that it can't be "decrypted", because there are more than one possible input value to the same output value. This is called the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

If the input is smaller or equal to the block size, then you *may* be able to decrypt the authentication tag to get the corresponding input. Whether you can do this depends on the actual MAC algorithm. For example [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC) has this *undesirable* property that short messages are simply encrypted which can lead to message forgeries and breaks in confidentiality. There are much better alternatives such as CMAC (OMAC1) which is also based on some block cipher or HMAC which is based on secure hash functions. **[`MACTripleDES` is an implementation of CBC-MAC](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/mactripledes.cs,26200fc6e34cc8b4,references) and should never be used.**

Usually, a MAC is used for authenticating a message. Since the receiver of the message knows both the message and the key that was used to create the MAC (authentication tag), she can run the MAC algorithm to produce the an authentication tag and compare it with the one that was sent along with the message. If both tags are equal then the receiver can be reasonably sure that the message or the tag wasn't manipulated during transmission.

Comment: thanks @ArtjomB. how can i decrypt as you mentioned when the input equal to block size.Then what is the use of MACTripleDES.

Comment: The [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/mactripledes.cs,26200fc6e34cc8b4,references) looks like CBC-MAC, so you should be able to directly decrypt it with Triple DES in ECB mode. I've described the usual use case of a MAC in the last paragraph.